# Efficient Cartesian product of unordered_map in c++

Tags: c++, cartesian-product

I used itertools.product() to generate the product of multiple lists of dictionaries in python.

Now I am trying to implement the basic cartesian product in c++ but it takes a lot of time to generate the products. Could you please give me some advice to make it more efficient? Thank you.

```
vector<vector<unordered_map<string, string>>> iter_product(\
                vector<vector<unordered_map<string, string>>> &maps_list){

  vector<vector<unordered_map<string, string>>> out;
  for (auto map = maps_list[0].begin(); map != maps_list[0].end(); map++){
    out.push_back(vector<unordered_map<string, string>>({*map}));
  }
  if (maps_list.size() > 1){
    for (int i = 1; i < maps_list.size(); i++){
      vector<vector<unordered_map<string, string>>> new_out;
      for (int j = 0; j < out.size(); j++){
        for (int k = 0; k < maps_list[i].size(); k++){
          out[j].push_back(maps_list[i][k]);
          new_out.push_back(out[j]);
        }
      }
      out = new_out;
    }
  }
  return out;
}
```

Comment: Well you create a whole bunch of identical copies of `std::unordered_map<string,string>` objects. That is going to be expensive. Python on the other hand does not copy any dictionaries, it's all references.

Comment: I tried to get the combination with reference, it works! thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As stated above, I also think you should use references as parameters and  not the actual vector. In addition you can pre-defined vector size if it is know.